# How do I call a Box<dyn FnOnce> stored inside a struct inside an enum?

Tags: rust

I store a `FnOnce` closure inside a struct inside an enum ([Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0960523985688277607cc5411caa64b3)):

```
pub struct ClosureContainer {
    closure: Box<dyn FnOnce(i32) -> i32>,
}

pub enum MathOperation {
    DoNothing,
    RunOperation(ClosureContainer),
}

impl MathOperation {
    pub fn doMath(&self, input: i32) -> i32 {
        match self {
            MathOperation::DoNothing => input,
            MathOperation::RunOperation(closureContainer) => (closureContainer.closure)(input),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let f = Box::new(move |input: i32| 4 * input);
    let closureContainer = ClosureContainer { closure: f };
    let operation = MathOperation::RunOperation(closureContainer);
    println!("{}", operation.doMath(5));
}
```

When I try to build, I get this error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `closureContainer.closure` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:14:62
   |
14 |             MathOperation::RunOperation(closureContainer) => (closureContainer.closure)(input),
   |                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `closureContainer.closure` has type `Box<dyn FnOnce(i32) -> i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

How do I set things up so that I can call this function?

Comment: Your question might be answered by the answers of [FnOnce inside Enum: cannot move out of borrowed content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32236430/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: See also [Why is calling a FnOnce closure a move?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53233803/155423)

Answer (score 2):

`FnOnce` can only be called once, so it needs to be consumed. If it's consumed, then the `ClosureContainer` must also be consumed (otherwise it's just an invalid struct). The fix, then, is to use `self` instead of `&self` in `doMath`:

```
pub struct ClosureContainer {
    closure: Box<dyn FnOnce(i32) -> i32>,
}

pub enum MathOperation {
    DoNothing,
    RunOperation(ClosureContainer),
}

impl MathOperation {
    pub fn doMath(self, input: i32) -> i32 {
        match self {
            MathOperation::DoNothing => input,
            MathOperation::RunOperation(closureContainer) => (closureContainer.closure)(input),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let f = Box::new(move |input: i32| 4 * input);
    let closureContainer = ClosureContainer { closure: f };
    let operation = MathOperation::RunOperation(closureContainer);
    println!("{}", operation.doMath(5));
}
```